# How to get search box to display correct criteria in Ruby on Rails with SQLITE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I created a search box on my index.html but it displays all database information instead of only displaying the information that was searched for.  Any ideas on how to get this to work properly?

Here is what I have...
I have a model called Article.  I set up a form on a controller called articles.  Within the articles table, I created the columns calibertitle, bullet, coal, caselength, powder, and text.  So the form grabs data and places them into these columns.

I have been displaying this info on articles/index.html with this in my articles_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end
```

I decided I wanted to create a search box where anyone can type in a keyword and if there is a match with the database, that particular info will be displayed.  I have '.308', '9mm', etc listed under the :calibertitle field for example.  So if a member types in one of the calibers I have in my database, it will display information only on that caliber.

Well I have a 2nd controller called welcome_controller.rb that is tied to the main index of my page.  Such as www.website.com/index.html

I have placed the search box on this page.
Here is my /app/views/welcome/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(articles_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Calibers" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

I have placed this in my app/models/article.rb

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  validates :calibertitle, presence: true,
                           length: { minimum: 3 }

  def self.search(search)
    where("calibertitle LIKE ? OR bullet LIKE ? OR powder LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}$
  end

end
```

^^ Is this correct for SQLITE?
I'm also not sure if something like this would work?...

```
where('calibertitle LIKE ?', "%#{params[:calibertitle]}%")
```

Here is my app/controllers/welcome_controllers.rb...

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
    if params[:search]
      @articles = Article.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @articles = Article.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end
end
```

When I enter a search term, it displays all of my table info instead of only the info I search for.  Any ideas on how to get it to only display data on what I search for?

Comment: Show related log from log/development.log when you call this action

Comment: http://pastie.org/10977886

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using Gem for searching in rails? one of the best option is https://github.com/ankane/searchkick (Intelligent search made easy with Rails and Elasticsearch). Searchkick learns what your users are looking for. As more people search, it gets smarter and the results get better. It’s friendly for developers - and magical for your users.

Comment: before I get into running Gems, I want to learn more about Rails

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.  I had updated the wrong controller.  I updated my articles controller instead of welcome controller and it worked.